# Optimize LINQ instead of creating new collections/loops

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have two tables:

**Invoices** (InvoiceID, InvoiceNumber)
**Invoices_Products** (InvoiceID, ProductID, IsFinalized)

I show a list of all invoices, and there are buttons to filter by "finalized" or "not finalized" invoices. A finalized invoice is one where *every* product on it is `IsFinalized==true`.

At the moment I have the following code which is performing quite slowly:

```
IEnumerable<Invoice> invoices = db.Invoices;

if (isFinalized) // filter by finalized invoices
{
    List<Invoice> unfinalizedInvoices = new List<Invoice>();

    foreach (var invoice in invoices)
    {
        int invoicesProductsCountTotal = db.Invoices_Products.Where(l => l.InvoiceID == invoice.InvoiceID).Count();
        int invoicesProductsCountFinalized = db.Invoices_Products.Where(l => l.InvoiceID == invoice.InvoiceID && l.IsFinalized == true).Count();

        if (invoicesProductsCountTotal != invoicesProductsCountFinalized)
        {
            unfinalizedInvoices.Add(invoice);
        }
    }

    invoices = invoices.Except(unfinalizedInvoices);
}
else
{
    List<Invoice> finalizedInvoices = new List<Invoice>();

    foreach (var invoice in invoices)
    {
        int invoicesProductsCountTotal = db.Invoices_Products.Where(l => l.InvoiceID == invoice.InvoiceID).Count();
        int invoicesProductsCountFinalized = db.Invoices_Products.Where(l => l.InvoiceID == invoice.InvoiceID && l.IsFinalized == true).Count();

        if (invoicesProductsCountTotal == invoicesProductsCountFinalized && invoicesProductsCountFinalized > 0)
        {
            finalizedInvoices.Add(invoice);
        }
    }

    invoices = invoices.Except(finalizedInvoices);
}
```

I realize this isn't optimal but I like spreading out my LINQ so that I can read and understand it.
**My question:** Is there any way I could make this query faster using `.All` or `.Any` or something, or do I need to rethink my database design (possibly adding an extra column to the Invoices table)

**edit:** Third table is **Products** (ProductID, ProductNumber) but you knew that

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you're loading all your invoices and then loading the products for each invoice. This is bound to be slow (and it will become a lot slower when you start adding a lot of invoice).

You should create a many-to-many relationship in EntityFramework. (see  [example](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx))

Your classes would look like this:

```
class Invoice 
{
    List<Product> Products {get; set;}
}
class Product
{
    bool IsFinalized {get; set;}
}
```

Now you can use LINQ to make sure that only SQL statement is executed which fetches only the data you want:

```
var invoices = db.Invoices.Where(i => i.Products.All(p => p.IsFinalized == finalized));
```

Comment: Thanks. But I use `Invoices_Products` as the many-to-many linking table - it has a few columns like 'Quantity', 'SellingPrice', etc. (btw I'm not using code first - using database first)

Comment: You can still do that, but instead of a many-to-many you define two one-to-many relationships. Then you can traverse it with LINQ as well

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over each `Invoice` and then make additional requests to the database will be very slow. Let your query get all the informations at once and iterate through the results instead.

```
var result = from invoice in db.Invoices
             join invoicedProduct in db.Invoices_Products
               on invoice.InvoiceId equals invoicedProduct.InvoiceId
             select new
             {
                 InvoiceId = invoice.InvoiceId,
                 ProductId = invoicedProduct.ProductId,
                 IsFinalized = invoicedProuct.IsFinalized
             };

var grpResult = from record in result
                group record by record.ProductId into productGrp
                select productGrp;

foreach( var grp in grpResult )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "ProductId: " + grp.Key.ToString( ) );
    Console.WriteLine( "TotalCount: " + grp.Count( ).ToString( ) );
    Console.WriteLine( "Finalized: " + grp.Where( item => item.IsFinalized ).Count( ).ToString( ) );
}
```

Comment: Rather than using a `Join` followed immediately by a `GroupBy` you should just use a `GroupJoin` from the start.

Comment: @Viper, ta for the insight there

Comment: @Servy does it make a difference? The first statement won't be executed until the `foreach`. Never used a `GroupJoin` btw ;)

Comment: @Viper It'll simplify the code quite a lot; whether it'll affect the generated SQL I couldn't say; you'd have to try it and find out.  I wouldn't be surprised either way.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isFinalized)
{
    invoices = invoices.Where(l => l.Invoices_Products.All(m => m.IsFinalized == true));
}
else
{
    List<Invoice> finalizedInvoices = invoices.Where(l => l.Invoices_Products.All(m => m.IsFinalized == true)).ToList();
    invoices = invoices.Except(finalizedInvoices);
}
```

^^ this seems to have improved performance dramatically. oh well, thanks for listening